# Algebraic structures whose Hilbert-Poincaré series are special functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, special-functions

- Are there good examples of algebraic structures whose Hilbert-Poincaré series are that of special functions? I'm particularly interested in cases where complex analytic reasoning about those series sheds light on the algebraic structures in question.
- Is there a dictionary of algebraic structures whose Hilbert-Poincaré series correspond to special functions?

Edit: I've heard of Monstrous Moonshine -- and I'm aware that there is a Mathieu Moonshine, but neither of those gets us outside of the territory of modular forms.

Comment: If not modular, what kind of special functions would you like to have then?

Comment: Well, I meant that besides modular functions and Moonshine, and say the polylogarithms (see  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25428/what-is-special-about-polylogarithms-that-leads-to-so-many-interesting-identitie but it's not clear if the variation of mixed Hodge structure arises from treating polylogarithms as Hilbert Poincare series). But there are a lot which don't have integral or rational coefficients (Airy, Bessel, hypergeometrics) for instance, and given how fecund both Moonshine and the polylogarithms are, I can't imagine that there isn't data about algebraic structures in them.

Comment: Of course there is a lot of algebraic structures in them, there is a huge amount of books on this ([example](http://books.google.fr/books?id=q90L-URPZJIC&printsec=frontcover&hl=uk&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)). But you are asking about Hilbert series - this is much more specific requirement.

Answer (score 9):

**Example 1**

Let $G$ be the [Monster group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_group) and let $\rho_0,\rho_1,\rho_2\ldots$ be its irreducible representations ordered by dimension. Then 
$$\mathrm{dim}\left(V_{-1}\right)q^{-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathrm{dim}\left(V_k\right)q^k=j(\tau)-744,\qquad q=e^{2\pi i \tau},$$
where $j(\tau)$ denotes the [$j$-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant)  and $V_{-1}=\rho_0$, $V_1=\rho_1\oplus\rho_0$, $V_2=\rho_2\oplus\rho_1\oplus\rho_0$,
$V_3=\rho_3\oplus\rho_2\oplus\rho_1\oplus\rho_1\oplus\rho_0\oplus\rho_0$ etc.

There are many other examples of this type (e.g. McKay-Thompson series) and very far-reaching generalizations known under the general name of [Monstrous Moonshine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstrous_moonshine).

---

**Example 2**

Another example is the character of the generic Verma module of the [Virasoro algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virasoro_algebra) 
$$[L_m,L_n]=(m-n)L_{m+n}+\frac{c}{12}m(m^2-1)\delta_{m+n,0}.$$
Such module $M(c,\Delta)$ is generated by the action of $L_{n<0}$ on the highest weight state $|\Delta\rangle$ annihilated by all $L_{n>0}$ and satisfying $L_0|\Delta\rangle=\Delta|\Delta\rangle$. The states $L_{-n_k}\ldots L_{-n_1}|\Delta\rangle$ of the module are naturally labeled by partitions. Now the character is
\begin{align}
\chi(c,\Delta|q)=\mathrm{Tr}\,q^{L_0-c/24}=\frac{q^{\Delta+(1-c)/24}}{\eta(\tau)},\qquad q=e^{2\pi i\tau},
\end{align}
where $\eta(\tau)$ is the [Dedekind eta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function) arising from the sum over these partitions.